# How to get data source usernames of ALL reports?

Tags: powershell, power-bi-report-server

Based on [this MSDoc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/connect-data-source-apis-pre-oct-2020), I wrote below script that fetches datasource for individual RsItem, but we have over 800 reports and so I want to get a detailed list of all reports' usernames (I don't want to have specify each RsItem):

```
 Install-Module ReportingServicesTools
 # establish session w/ Report Server
 $session = New-RsRestSession -ReportPortalUri https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports
 # get data source object
 $dataSources = Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem '/RefreshInfoSample'
 # get username
 $dataSources[0].DataModelDataSource.Username
```

**Desired output**: A list like this

[image: list]

If there is more than one datasource connection/report, list usernames on individual rows separately.

How to achieve this?

I'm trying to adjust the script to something like this, but not sure the correct approach to loop through the items:

```
# establish session w/ Report Server
     $session = New-RsRestSession -ReportPortalUri https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports
foreach (-RsItem $item) {
 # get data source object
 $dataSources = Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem $item
 # get username
 $dataSources[0].DataModelDataSource.Username
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @postanote answer, below is solution:

```
$webPortalURL = "https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports"

$PBI_Reports_Array = @()

$PBI_Reports_Array = $(Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $($webPortalURL + "/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports"))

$session = New-RsRestSession -ReportPortalUri $webPortalURL

foreach ($reportPath in $PBI_Reports_Array.value.path) {
    Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem $reportPath | foreach {$PSItem[0].DataModelDataSource.Username}
}
```

Another way that executes faster:

```
# lists all the reports on the server that are available to your user account
Function listReports($baseURL) {
    $reports = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri "$baseURL/api/v2.0/CatalogItems"
    $reports.value | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "PowerBIReport"} | foreach { 
            #Write-Host ("{0} {1}" -f $_.Id, $_.Name)
            return $_.Id
    }
}

Function getDataSources($baseURL, $reportID) {
    $sources = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri "$baseURL/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports($reportID)/DataSources"
    if ($sources.value -is [array]) {
        return $sources.value
    } else {
        return @($sources.value)
    }
}

$reportIDs = @(listReports("https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports"))

foreach($reportID in $reportIDs) {
    (getDataSources "https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports" $reportID | % {
        return $_.DataModelDataSource.Username
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a Reporting Server to test this on ***(so, pseudocode to follow)***. You are not showing where `$item` is coming from or what is in it, but in the normal loop context, this...

```
# establish session w/ Report Server
     $session = New-RsRestSession -ReportPortalUri https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports
foreach (-RsItem $item) {
 # get data source object
 $dataSources = Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem $item
 # get username
 $dataSources[0].DataModelDataSource.Username
}
```

.. is not valid syntax. If you are doing this in the Powershell_ISE or VSCode, IntelliSense and PScriptAnalyzer will make this ...

```
(-RsItem $item)
```

... is error code.

The above should either be something like this...

```
$session = New-RsRestSession -ReportPortalUri 'https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports'
foreach ($item in $session ) 
{
    $dataSources = Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem $item
    $dataSources[0].DataModelDataSource.Username
}
```

... or something like this:

```
$session = New-RsRestSession -ReportPortalUri 'https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports' | 
foreach {
    $dataSources = Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $PSItem -RsItem $item
    $dataSources[0].DataModelDataSource.Username
}
```

Yet it appears that this is the list you are trying for:

```
$dataSources = Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem '/RefreshInfoSample'
```

So, then something like this:

```
$session = New-RsRestSession -ReportPortalUri 'https://sql-dev02.domain.com/Reports'

Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem $item | 
foreach {$PSItem[0].DataModelDataSource.Username}
```

If you are not using a PowerShell editor like the ISE/VSCode, and want to see check your code via the console host, then use the `Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer` cmdlet...

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Examples
Get-help -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Online
```

...and view the call stack on your code to see what is happening, then use the `Trace-Command` cmdlet.

```
(Get-Command -Name Trace-Command).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Trace-Command).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Examples
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Full
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Online
```

Comment: `$item` is supposed to be the report path, which is what i was struggling to get in bulk. no matter i improvised on your answer and posted a solution :)

Comment: No worries, and glad it gave the direction for you to come to a resolution. Take care and stay safe.